# Convert Column Heading to row data - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Query Print result like

```
North   South   West    East    Central
0       280     0       41      36
```

But I want it Like

```
North    0
South    280
West     0
East     41
Central  36
```

SQL:-

```
Select  Count(Case When Region=1 Then 1 Else Null End)[North],
    Count(Case When Region=2 Then 1 Else Null End)[South],
    Count(Case When Region=3 Then 1 Else Null End)[West],
    Count(Case When Region=4 Then 1 Else Null End)[East],
    Count(Case When Region=5 Then 1 Else Null End)[Central] 
    From ATM Where ATMStatus=0 And Bank=1
```

Comment: What is the schema of table ATM ?

Comment: Instead of Column and Below Thier Values i want Rows of Column Heading and in front of their Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE Group by

```
SELECT 
   CASE Region 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'North'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'South' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'West'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'East'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Central' END AS Region  
    , COUNT(ID)   --or your primary key if it is different
FROM ATM
WHERE ATMStatus = 0 AND Bank = 1
GROUP BY Region
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select case Region
     when 1 then 'North'
     when 2 then 'South'
     etc

 end, count(*)
 From ATM Where ATMStatus=0 And Bank=1  
 group by Region
```

Do you have a region table? That would make it simpler, especially if the 0 rows are important.